# Java Error. Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, error-handling

I have written a simple Java program and want to run it through the console

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I tried to run the app with many files and it didn't work, I tried a simple hello world but it also gives me an error
Comand Line:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyJ4q.png)
Files in the project:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQkj2.png)

The HelloWorld.class file was created in the folder after the javac command HelloWorld.java, but an error occurs when the java command HelloWorld is entered

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Try `java -cp . HelloWorld`

Comment: Is that the complete source file or is there a `package` statement?

Comment: @DavidConrad is the full text of the program

Comment: You've messed up your classpath environment variable. Run `java -cp . HelloWorld`. Or, did you add a package statement? Don't do that if you want to set it up like this.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me,you'd better check about your settings on Java.Is the command `java --version` and `javac --version` works in this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as it will work for all versions of Java. I presume you don't have a package declaration in your source file.  From within the same directory as your `HelloWorld.java` file, do the following:

- type `javac`.  It should print a series of command line arguments.  This will at least ensure your console shell/cmdline processor can find the compiler.
  -if not, ensure your environment class path points to where Java is installed.
- once found, do `javac HelloWorld.java`
- a `HelloWorld.class` file should be in the same directory.
- now type `java` to see if it can find the JVM runtime environment.
- if so, then type `java HelloWorld` and it should run.

If any of the above fail, check out Oracle or do a web search for installing Java on your particular operating system.

Note more recent versions of Java will let you compile and run the code by doing `java HelloWorld.java`.